# Eclipse plugin to show a thorough call hierarchy between Java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, code-analysis

I'm using eclipse Kepler and I need a plugin to determine for a project which methods of other projects of the workspace/working set are being used. Much like the "Call Hierarchy", but automatically for all classes and methods.

Is there an existing plugin that can do that? A visualization isn't necessarily needed, a result table suffices.

Comment: And what's the problem you're having?

Comment: My problem is, that the call hierarchy does this only for a single selected method, but I need a complete overview of all call hierarchies.

Comment: So you want somebody to write the code for you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone has done this before, but I didn't find such a plugin. Maybe I overlooked something, that's why I ask here what plugin might do that.

Comment: Although not strictly an "call hierarchy on steroids" that you're asking for, have a look at https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/

Comment: That sounds good, but unfortunately not working with Kepler https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codepro-analytix/D1vZvOGe-yE

Comment: Does JDepend plugin helps you http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jdepend4eclipse#.Uw73iR9sM38 ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will evaluate all these plugins tonight. @E-Riz, ChandrayyaGK Please turn your comments into answers, so I can possibly reward you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [JDepend4Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jdepend4eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=) plugin.

> JDepend traverses a set of Java class and source file directories and
>   generates design quality metrics for each Java package. JDepend allows
>   you to automatically measure the quality of a design in terms of its
>   extensibility, reusability, and maintainability to effectively manage
>   and control package dependencies. Package dependency cycles are
>   reported along with the hierarchical paths of packages participating
>   in package dependency cycles.
>
> The tool helps greatly by refactoring old & huge source code
>   repositories with cyclic package dependencies between packages.

[image: JDepend4Eclipse screenshot]

Shishir

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get what you want with a reverse-engineering tool. They are many out there of various qualities and maturities, I would recommend [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/). From my experience it still works reasonably well with big code bases, has nice and interactive visualizations.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse plugin "creole", with it's advanced call-hierarchy feature, worked great for me, on this type of large scale Java software analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse UML plugin may help u... Try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ucdetector.org/

> UCDetector (Unnecessary Code Detector - pronounced "You See Detector")
>   is a eclipse PlugIn tool to **find unnecessary (dead) public java code**.
>   For example public classes, methods or fields which have no
>   references. UCDetector creates markers for the following problems,
>   which appear in the eclipse problem view: Unnecessary (dead) code Code
>   where the visibility could be changed to protected, default or private
>   Methods or fields, which can be final

Works with multiple projects, too